# Apache 2.4 en Windows Server 2008 no carga la extensión php_intl

Tags: php, apache, windows

Buenas estimados, tengo un problema a la hora de hacer cargar la extensión php_intl:

- PHP Version: 5.6.20
- Sistema:     Windows NT SERVER1 6.1 build 7600 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Compiler:     MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
- Arquitectura:    x64
- Archivo de configuracion: C:\php\php.ini

Otras herramientas:

- Visual C++ Redistributable para Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 - instalado
- Apache and PHP - instalados individualmente, no wamp

La extensión **php_intl.dll** nunca se carga. Las demás librarías se cargan sin problemas. De hecho, cuando reinicio apache veo el siguiente error en los logs:

> [Wed Jul 06 14:41:03.632426 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14964:tid 356] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 14992
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

El dll si está en la carpeta de extensiones, o sea, el path está bien. Finalmente fui a la [página de descarga de Intl en Pecl](https://pecl.php.net/package/intl) y parace ser que los repositorias allí no son compatibles con Windows Server 2008.

No sé qué más hacer para encontrar la causa de este problema.

> **Notas adicionales**: Copié las carpetas de Apache24/ y php/ a una máquina con Windows 7 machine 64x ahí si cargó sin ningún inconveniente.

Comment: Tienes la carpeta de PHP en tu PATH? Así se localizan los dll `icud*.dll`, php_intl.dll los necesita para funcionar.

Comment: Así es,  esa carpeta si está registrada en el path,  ¿pero esos dll icud* no corresponden a wamp?  No los reconozco

Comment: No corresponden solo a wamp, son los dll de Unicode, por eso los necesita php_intl.dll. Estan en la carpeta de PHP?

Comment: Volví a revisar los paths, y noto que había registrado `C:\php\ext` en vez de `C:\php`. Demasiadas gracias. Por favor agregue su comentario como una respuesta para darla por aceptada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php_intl.dll requiere acceso a los dll Unicode (icu*.dll) que están en la carpeta raíz de php, php_intl.dll los ubica por medio del PATH, por eso hay que registrar c:\php (por ejemplo) en el PATH.